# Curious overload resolution when using a naked null literal with user-defined operators

Tags: c#, null, operator-overloading, overload-resolution, lifted-operators

(The "user-defined" in the title refers to the fact that addition and subtraction of `TimeSpan` and `DateTime` are not a part of the C# standard. They are defined in the BCL.)

Playing around with lifted operators on nullable `TimeSpan` and `DateTime` values, I wrote the following code. Note that the framework offers different operations on `TimeSpan` and `DateTime`.

There's one symmetrical (and commutative) addition where you take in two `TimeSpan` and return the sum `TimeSpan`. The "inverse" of this addition is the subtraction of two `TimeSpan` yielding a `TimeSpan`.

Then there's another kind of addition, asymmetrical, where you take one `DateTime` (left operand) and one `TimeSpan` (right operand) to produce a `DateTime`. Because of the asymmetry of this operation, it has two "kinds" of inverses: One where you subtract two `DateTime` from each other to get the `TimeSpan` difference, and one where you have one `DateTime` and subtract from it one `TimeSpan` to produce a result `DateTime`.

```
static void Main()
{
  DateTime? n_dt = new DateTime(2012, 12, 25);
  TimeSpan? n_ts = TimeSpan.FromDays(62.0);

  var a = n_dt + n_ts;   // OK
  var b = n_ts + n_ts;   // OK

  var c = null + n_dt;   // OK, string concatenation! Type of expression is String
  var d = null + n_ts;   // OK, compiler prefers TS+TS, not DT+TS
  var e = n_dt + null;   // OK, DT+TS
  var f = n_ts + null;   // OK, TS+TS
  var g = null + null;   // error, type of expression is undetermined

  var h = n_dt - n_dt;   // OK
  var i = n_dt - n_ts;   // OK
  var j = n_ts - n_ts;   // OK

  var k = null - n_dt;   // OK, DT-DT
  var l = null - n_ts;   // compiler prefers TS-TS, not DT-TS
  var m = n_dt - null;   // error, compiler won't choose between DT-DT amd DT-TS, type of expression is undetermined
  var n = n_ts - null;   // OK, TS-TS
  var o = null - null;   // OK, integer subtraction! Type of expression is Nullable<Int32>

  // illegal:
//var p = n_dt + n_dt;
//var q = n_ts + n_dt;
//var r = n_ts - n_dt;
}
```

Some questions arise naturally.

It's a bit strange that `o` is allowed and gives an `int?` (why not a `long?` by the way?) while `g` is disallowed. Is this in the spec? Also, it's a little strange that the "impossible" `c` is resolved by string concatenation. Apparently the compiler decides that the `null` in `c` is a `(string)null`. Adding an expression of explicit type `object` to a `DateTime`, on the other hand, will not compile.

But my main question is: **Why can the compiler choose an overload for `d` and `l`, but with `m` it complains about ambiguity?**

Comment: By-far the weirdest thing here is var o = null - null;

Comment: `c` uses string concatenation because language operators are preferred over user defined operators, and that expression matches the string concatenation operator of `operator +(string, object)`.  That of course raises the question of `d` though, as by that logic that should also resolve to string concatenation.

Comment: @DaveBish Agreed.  I'd assume it would be ambigous between int/long

Comment: @DaveBish Ah, found the answer.  Section 7.3.6 of the C# specs; it determines how, when given two numeric types, it determines which operator to use.  `int` has the highest precedence on the list.

Comment: @Servy - The inference to int? still feels pretty weird!!

Comment: @Servy and I suppose that `null + null` is ambiguous between `(int?)null + (int?)null` and `(string)null + (object)null`, while no such ambiguity exists for the binary `-` operator.

Comment: @phoog That's exactly right, and since the string operator isn't numeric it isn't subject to 7.3.6 for resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason seems to be that with `m`, the two possible operations are **defined** inside the same type, namely `System.DateTime`. There's no way to choose between them.

On the other hand, with `d` and `l`, one operation is defined in `System.TimeSpan`, and the other one is defined in `System.DateTime`. But in the lines of `d` and `l`, we see `TimeSpan`, but there's no mention of any `DateTime` type what so ever in the assignments of `d` and `l`. It seems like the compiler then only searches through operators defined in the type `System.TimeSpan`, and forgets to search through user-defined operators defined in all other types (which would by the way be very many types to search). In that way, during the resolution of `d` and `l`, the compiler never discovers the operators defined inside the `DateTime` type.

Comment: See section 7.3.4 of the C# spec, as it appears to be relevant and to confirm this answer.